# Prevent Javascript event when clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have a problem mixing associating two JavaScript functions.

I have a table sortable with tablesorter Jquery plugin.
Inside my table header, I have a button "refresh" to update content table in Ajax.

The problem is that click event seems to be prevented by sort event, and I don't know how to fix that.

**Edit**: I would like the table no to be sorted when updating the table

Here is my table layout:

```
<table class="container-content" align="center" id="tableUserByAppli">
  <thead>
    <tr class="container-title">
      <th>
        <button id="btnAppli">
          <img width="16" alt="reload" src="img/refresh-icon.png">
        </button>
        Application
      </th>
      <th>
        Users
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

And Js code:

```
$(function()
{
    $("#btnAppli").click(function()
    {
        ajaxUpdateUsersByAppli;
    });

    // dynamically set table to sortable (tablesorter)
    $("table").addClass("tablesorter");
    $("table").tablesorter({
        sortReset : true
    });

});
```

A JSFiddle to run my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/33rrd/

Comment: What is the problem here? You only run the sort on page load, so I don't see how it can be affected by returning false from the button click.

Comment: remove   return false;

Comment: have you stored a function in the variable `ajaxUpdateUsersByAppli` or is `ajaxUpdateUsersByAppli` a function by itself?

Comment: @PratikJoshi Done. 
Return false was a test, but it does nothing, and ajaxUpdateUsersByAppli is a function by itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues that need to be addressed in the shared demo ([updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/33rrd/2/)).

First, to ignore button clicks, wrap the header titles in a div, then target them using the [`selectorSort` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#selectorsort)

HTML

```
<th>
    <button id="btnAppli">
      Update
    </button>
    <div class="title">Application</div>
</th>
```

CSS (to reposition the button)

```
th button {
    float: left;
}
```

Script

```
$("table").tablesorter({
    sortReset : true,
    selectorSort: '.title'
});
```

Second, the table headers are rebuilt within the plugin, so any event binding would need to be delegated:

```
$("table").on("click", "#btnAppli", function(){
    alert("test");
    //ajaxUpdateUsersByAppli;
});
```

Comment: What a better answer than the one provided by the creator... Thank you, it works perfectly and i should have read more the documentation

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is alright, just remove the return false; as suggested by Pratik also, if you are returning false on the button click's response then whatever computation you do inside the click event will be useless.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/nsq2k/

You needed to add the argument e (short for the event) to the function, and call `e.preventDefault()`. Check my forked fiddle above.

Answer (score 0):

**try this work well:**

```
$(function()
{


    // dynamically set table to sortable (tablesorter)
    $("table").addClass("tablesorter");
    $("table").tablesorter({
        sortReset : true
    });
});
$("#btnAppli").click(function(e)
    {

       alert("test");

        //ajaxUpdateUsersByAppli;
    });
```

Comment: It works, but is there a way to prevent sorting when updating the table?

Comment: After update the table call these function it's work fine.      $("table").addClass("tablesorter");
    $("table").tablesorter({
        sortReset : true
});

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue, ie, prevent the sorting script from being executed during an ajax load... I could however trap the click event.

Here is the dirty solution I found after looking into tablesorter code.
Set isUpdating property of the table to [true] will prevent the sort from  happening.

document.getElementById("table").isUpdating = true;

Don't forget to set it back to [false] into your callback ajax events...